# Current Month and Year in Subject for Automated Batch Job E-mail

Tags: php, date, batch-file, time

I'm using a PHP file to send statistics at the beginning of every month regarding the report for the previous month.  However in the subject of the e-mail it must say the previous Month (e.g. 05) and the current year (e.g. 2013).  And as time goes on this number should go up automatically without any editing. I was wondering how I could edit the existing code to display this?  Any help would be appreciated. I was thinking of a function that could display the current month and year and I could minus 1 from the month to display the previous month?

Current Code:

```
$email_subject = "(MM-YYYY) Report for MS-SQL.";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
$lastMonth = date('m-Y',strtotime('last month'));
$email_subject = "($lastMonth) Report for MS-SQL.";
```

If you want yesterday:

```
$yesterday = date('m-d-Y',strtotime('yesterday')); // Change format as needed
```

Comment: $lastMonth = date('m-Y',strtotime('last month');

Comment: Gah, I always tend to drop parenthesis. I've fixed it.

Comment: How would I get the name of the month to show (e.g. May) instead of the number of the month?

Comment: You can use M (3 characters) or F (full month name). Check the link above to see all of the different format characters you can use.

Comment: how would it look like if I wanted 1 day before the current day instead of one month before?  Is it d instead of m?  Could you edit the code to show me please.